# Discord.py - Detecting Reactions in DMs, wait_for('reaction_add') incorrect Message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, dm

I'm having an odd issue when trying to detect a reaction on a sent DM.
First, I'm checking if the `!hello` command is being run, then sending the author of that message a DM asking if they like the bot. The user is to input their opinion using the Reactions and get a response in the original channel of the `!hello` command. What I have found is that the message it is `wait_for` is not the sent DM, but the previously sent `!hello` command. Perhaps I have overlooked something in documentation, but how do I change what message the Bot should be listening for? Any help or pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

```
import discord
import asyncio

# Set up the bot
token = "TOKEN"
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, message_content=True, guilds=True, reactions=True)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!hello"):
        try:
            # Send the DM
            dm = await message.author.send("Hello! Do you like this bot? React with  or ")
            # React to the message with the options
            await dm.add_reaction('')
            await dm.add_reaction('')
            # Wait for the user's reaction
            def check(reaction, user):
                return user != client.user and str(reaction.emoji) in ['', '']
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=15.0, check=check)
            # Do something with the reaction
            if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
                await message.channel.send(f'{user.name} liked the bot')
            elif str(reaction.emoji) == '':
                await message.channel.send(f'{user.name} did not like the bot')
        except discord.Forbidden:
            await message.channel.send("I'm sorry, I am unable to send you a DM.")
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.channel.send("You did not react in time.")

client.run(token)
```

I have gone through several Stack Overflow posts describing similar issues, but none have explicitly solved my problem. The biggest thing I suspect could be intents, but I cannot pinpoint which intents nor Discord Developer Portal Permissions that have to be enabled. And I would prefer to keep my bot not fully capable of destroying a server with Admin Permissions.

Comment: Just add it to your check.....? That's what the check is for... Also is there any valid reason you're manually parsing message content instead of just using the `Commands` framework?

Comment: @stijndcl, How do I add the specific `dm` to the check, because it seems to default to the `!help` message instead, unless I'm misunderstanding? Hmm I'll take a look at the Commands framework too.

Comment: You already have the Message instance of the DM message, so just check if the id of the message that the reaction was placed on is the same as the id of the DM message...?

Comment: I have already tried that. It's as if the DM channel doesn't exist. In many of the other DM code excerpts of other users, they seem to all use the `members` intent, but when adding that to mine, I receive an error even though in the Developer Portal I have Administrator enabled as a test. What more must I enable to be able to use the `members` intents?

Comment: "I receive an error" is completely useless info. Add the traceback to your post... And intents have nothing to do with admin permissions. Read the docs https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that intents are separate from permissions. That was something I had confused. Have a nice day. (ɴᴏ ɴᴇᴇᴅ ᴛᴏ ʙᴇ ᴄᴏɴᴅᴇsᴄᴇɴᴅɪɴɢ, ʏᴏᴜ'ʀᴇ ɴᴏᴛ ғᴏʀᴄᴇᴅ ᴛᴏ ʙᴇ ʜᴇʀᴇ)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem I was having lies in Intents. The necessary Intent required for a Bot to read reactions using `wait_for('reaction_add')` within a DM are the `GUILD_MEMBER` Privileged Intents. (Not realising they are separate from Bot Permissions)
All that had to be done was include `members=True` within my set of subscribed Intents.
Example from code above: `intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, message_content=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True)`

[Here is where the required Privileged Intent can be found within the Developer Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33dgz.png)

Hope this helps someone with the same issue I had.